# Woocommerce functionality is inhibited after AJAX page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I have an ajax transition which is this:

```
function fadeTransition(href = window.location.href) {

  $('.fader').css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    //        'height': h,
    'height': '100vh',
    'width': '0',
    'left': '0',
    'top': '0',
    'color': 'black',
    'background-color': 'black',
    'z-index': '300'
  }).animate({
    'width': '100vw',
  }, 400, function() {
    $('.slider-transition').load(href + ' .slider-transition', function() {
      //            EXECUTES ON CALLBACK
      // $('.slider-transition').children('.slider-transition').unwrap();
      //            h = $(document).height();
      $('.fader').animate({
        'left': '100vw'
      }, 400, function() {
        slideShowInit();
        initParalax();
        $('.woocommerce-product-gallery').each(function() {
          $(this).wc_product_gallery();
        });
        $('.slider-transition').children('.slider-transition').unwrap();
        // $('.slider-transition').parents('.slider-transition').unwrap();
      });
    });
  });
}
```

It's a simple transition that loads the element from the next page into the element of the current page and by attaching all of the click events to the body as such:

```
$('body').on('click', '.main-menu li a, nav a, a.button, a.square, a.grow', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});
$("li").on("click", "a", function(event) {
  var _href = $(this).attr("href");
  history.pushState(null, null, _href);
  fadeTransition(_href);
});
```

I've been able to circumnavigate the problem of click events being destroyed after the transition. The only problem that with the Woocommerce plugin in Wordpress, I can't possibly hope to traverse the entire assets folder of JS and replace

```
$('.a').on('click', function() {});
```

with

```
$('.body').on('click', 'a', function() {});
```

and attach all of the DOM events to the body like this and even then I'm only 70% sure this is the problem, does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

**Remove an event handler with jQuery using [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/)**

With jQuery **to stop/remove existing "click" delegated event** that interfere with your own custom click event, you could try to use [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), which is likely the contrary of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

So with your code it should be:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    $(document.body).off('click', 'a');

    $("li").on("click", "a", function(event) {
        var _href = $(this).attr("href");
        history.pushState(null, null, _href);
        fadeTransition(_href);
    });
});
```

It could solve your issue.

Comment: This is the idea but for Woocommerce, it seems there are things that there are several click events, load events, and I'm not sure what else, the layout of some pages looks different after reloading the page instead of navigating to it with Ajax. One solution I found was possibly to reload all of the JS in the head but this causes a tremendous slow down.